# Looping through all attributes of item in EL

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

BalusC can probably answer this for me.

I have a list of strings that I am setting as an attribute in the request object. Each of these strings represents a table header that I will print out on the page.

I then will be including a jsp for each object of type "process" that I am getting elsewhere. Each process object has the same attributes but some of filled and some are not.

This is the goal: For each process, loop through each string in the list of column names. If the attribute on this process that matches the string has a value, then I want to display the value, otherwise I will be leaving that cell blank.

Bascially, what I am asking for is a way to do recursion in EL and JSTL such that I can check each attribute in a process.

If any of this does not make sense or you need more expanation, please ask.

**EDIT**

```
<c:forEach items="${colNames}" var="cName"><%--colNames is the list of strings --%>
    <c:forEach items="${item.values}" var="value"><%--item is the process whose attributes I want to iterate through --%>
            <c:if test="item has attribute that matches cName">
                <td><c:out value="${value}"/></td><%--if item has an attribute that matches the string in the list, then I want to print out the value of that attribute--%>
            </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: <c:forEach items="${your list}" var="item"> or is this not what you mean?

Comment: I'll add an edit so that it is more clear.

Comment: Woah! Why the down vote?

Comment: <c:if test="${cName == value}">
                <td><c:out value="${value}"/></td>
            </c:if>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<c:forEach items="${colNames}" var="cName">
    <c:forEach items="${item.values}" var="value">
            <c:choose>
               <c:when test="${cName==value}">
                   <td><c:out value="${cName}"/></td>
               </c:when>
               <c:otherwise>
                   <td></td>
               </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```